Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
My target SDK is 34, after flutter upgrade and clean, downloading of new dependencies.
Using latest version of google_sign_in (^6.2.2), Java 17.
> flutter build appbundle --debug     

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':google_sign_in_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: ~/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path ~/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/a8ccf02f3bd250ddd23a149d57050286-edb8a5f8-325c-4293-8c19-e22390005e69/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output ~/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/a8ccf02f3bd250ddd23a149d57050286-edb8a5f8-325c-4293-8c19-e22390005e69/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Running Gradle task 'bundleDebug'...                               10.0s
Gradle task bundleDebug failed with exit code 1

> java --version
openjdk 17.0.5 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8, mixed mode, sharing)

Tried downgrading the dependency to 6.1.6 and older. Works well on release.

Apparently flutter was using a different version of Java than the default java placed at /usr/bin/java.
By running java --version it showed version 17, yet using flutter doctor -v I was able to see Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21...) which was supplied with Android Studio (Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/...)
Changing the java version using flutter config --jdk-dir /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/ to version 17, matching the gradle version, fixed the problem.
